# rails caching or locally storing query parameters?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching, session-storage

I try to store a query string for an API call so that I can use it again for the next 30 or 60 or any more results. When I used caching in Rails the query is passed on between different computers in the internet. That is not what I wanted to do. It should be only for one user and then this one user who is not logged in or something can get the next results pressing on a link.

So I tried javascript instead grabbing the input from the textfield and then storing it in a sessionStorage. It works once and then I do not know how to change that sessionStorage again.

Code is below. Any ideas how to properly store query strings in rails for the next api call?

Model 1

```
def self.search_results(search_term_web, params_web)


        Rails.cache.write 'searchterm', search_term_web

        results = good.search(search_term_web)

end
```

Model 2

```
def self.search_results_again(params_web)


        results = good.search(Rails.cache.write 'searchterm')

end
```

Controller

```
def search


    if params[:q]


        @params_web = {:count =>30, :offset => 0}
        params[:bing] = @params_web


        @q = User.search_results(params[:q], params[:good])


            if @q

           #    render json: @q

             render partial: "cognitives/q"   

            else

            render status: :not_found, nothing: true

           end   

    end

end


def search30

    if  Rails.cache.read 'searchterm'

        @params_web = {:count =>30, :offset => 30}
        params[:bing] = @params_web


        @q = User.search_results_again(params[:good])


            if @q

           #   render json: @q

            render partial: "cognitives/q"   

            else

            render status: :not_found, nothing: true

           end   
     end

end
```

Another approach using Javascript

```
var addsearchterm = function (){

  localStorage.begriff = document.getElementById('web-    text').value;
  document.getElementById('begriff').innerHTML = localStorage.begriff;
};

   addsearchterm();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a per user cache you can use the session id as part of the cache key:

```
cache_key = session.id + search_term_web.to_query
Rails.cache.write({ id: session.id }, search_term_web)
```

You could also use a user id or any other unique identifier. You are not limited to using strings as cache keys - you can use arrays or hashes as well.

You can also store things in the session storage - however [the default store (CookieStore)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores) has a very limited size imposed by the browser on cookies. If you intend to store something like the response from an API call you should use another storage mechanism such as Redis or Memcached.

However the session is not available in the model - either you need to pass the session into your model or handle caching in the controller.

Comment: thank you for the idea. But it did not work in my code. This one did the trick finally.   request_ip = request.ip
        
            session[request_ip] = params[:q]